# MVC6: How to load scripts conditionally only for IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my _Layout.cshtml page I want to include some scripts only for IE (IE11 if we want to be accurate);

I tried the following

```
<!--[if IE]><!--><script src="some.script.min"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```

but it does not work - it takes it as regular comment. I am testing on IE11.

I found this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10/) saying that conditional comments are removed from IE10.

So what can I do here?

Comment: Well, first of all, can you explain why you want to include these scripts in IE11?  You should strive to write your code to be browser agnostic.  What do you need to do only in IE11?  Chances are you can do it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It appears IE 10+ will recognize the following:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This results in the conditional statement being passed over as an HTML comment in IE 10+ (resulting in the scripts being loaded), but recognized as conditional and omitted by anything lower than IE 10.